# MVC DataAnnotations remove error message

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following view model field :

```
[Required]
[StringLength(9)]
[RegularExpression(@"\d{9}", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Number_Format", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyTypeOfResource))]
public string Number{ get; set; }
```

The Regular expression filter will take care of the input larger than 9 characters and right format and display its validation message, but the `StringLength` will display its own default error message as well. Removing the `[StringLength(9)]` will solve the problem of two different messages, but I assume this filter provides valuable information to SQL about the data type maximum size. Is there any other way ? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `StringLength` and have only:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"\d{9}", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Number_Format", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyTypeOfResource))]
public string Number{ get; set; }
```

You should be good. The `RequiredAttribute` will validate the property is set, and the `RegularExpressionAttribute` will validate that it is a string of 9 characters that are all digits.

**edit:**

Regarding the comment about assuming the filter provides valuable information to SQL... No, it's not meant to do this.  DataAnnotations are meant to bridge the gab between client and presentation-layer validations.  MVC does use DataAnnotations internally to validate a ViewModel, but a ViewModel is not necessarily (read: should not be) considered a domain model.  A ViewModel is a model of what you want to display to a user while a domain model is usually representative of the data.

I wrote a blog a while ago that walks you through DataAnnotations within MVC 3 and how the framework turns them into unobtrusive JavaScript validations on the client side.  It is definitely worth checking out.

[Code is here](https://github.com/jimschubert/ContainsAttributeExample) and [blog is here](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/08/dataannotations-mvc3-unobtrusive-validations/).

Answer (score 1):

Change the StringLength attribute to include a blank error message, like so:

```
[StringLength(9, ErrorMessage = "")]
```

Comment: It seems the empty string does not work any more. I had to add at least a space.